# How to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in Razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor, directoryservices

I installed `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` from NuGet and I'm able to use it in my controllers. I'm trying to use `@UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress` in a Razor view. I added the namespace to `Views/Web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This left me with an error, so I also added the assembly reference:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

I obtained that public key token from `sn -T`. But I'm still getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What have I done wrong, or what else do I need to do?

Comment: Not messing with web.config, what happens if you do this: `@System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress` ?

Comment: @mxmissile "The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea why I can't directly refer to classes in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. But using them indirectly works as expected:

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    public static string GetEmail()
    {
        return UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
    }
}
```

I reverted my previous changes to `Views/Web.config` and added the namespace where this class resides. Now I can use `@UserHelper.GetEmail()` in Razor.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` should have `"Copy local"` on `'True'`.
Honestly, I see no reason why that should work, because that is a Framework library, but changing that setting worked for me.